# How to send a message with a Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried to make a Discord Bot but I have struggled with making the bot send a message into the server. i wrote this code that receives messages from the servers and prints them in the terminal, if anyone could answer this with a way to just repeat the message that was sent by the bot that would be great.

```py
import discord


client = discord.Client()

token = 'My token'

# bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        
        print(client.user.name)
        print(client.user.id)
        print('Discord.py Version: {}'.format(discord.__version__))
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # print message content in terminal
    print(message.content)


client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sends a message whenever someone sends 'Happy Birthday' to the text channel.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
            return
    if message.content.lower() == "happy birthday":
            await message.channel.send("happy Birthday!")
    # print message content in terminal
    print(message.content)
```

You can use this as an example.

Comment: @Odd'sAdventures You can do that by replacing the `if` statement with `if  "happy birthday" in message.content.lower()`

Comment: @Odd'sAdventures This will check if the message is in the content instead of checking if it is at the start or the end.

Answer (score 0):

```py
await message.channel.send("Bot's message")
```

Comment: Please add some commentary as to how this answer the question. Specifically it could be helpful if you explained where this line of code should go